# How to switch between php versions? php -v shows 8.2 but phpinfo() shows 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to switch from php **7.4** to **8.2** using command `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and after doing it and restarting apache2 `php -v` shows version **8.2**, but `phpinfo()` shows **7.4**.

Command `sudo a2enmod php8.2` throws "ERROR: Module php8.2 does not exist!"

Command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.2` throws: "Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php8.2"

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]